# Aggregated CMPedometerData (iPhone + Watch total count)

Tags: ios, iphone, watchkit, apple-watch, core-motion

My app collects **CMPedometerData both on the iPhone and the Watch**.

iPhone's steps number (both in real time and historical data) are significantly lower than those recorded by the Watch (witch makes sense, since "on device" steps are actually lower when you always wear the Watch while sometimes leaving the phone on the desk).

The fact is, the Watch seems to have the aggregated data, or at least since it's the higher step count the most significant data, so **I'd like to have those aggregated / higher data on the iPhone app too**.

Do I need to collect them on both devices and merge them manually? **Is there a way to get the aggregated data from CMPedometer, since Apple is already doing the merge behind the scenes?**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HealthKit uses `HKStatisticsQuery` and `HKStatisticsCollectionQuery` to compute the aggregated step count from several devices. These methods automatically detect overlaps in the measurements and get rid of the duplicate entries.

You can find some sample in in the [official documentation of HKStatisticsQuery](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkstatisticsquery).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm honestly not thrilled to have to ask users permission both to access the CMPedometer data and HealthKit data, but if that's the only way to go... I guess that means that you'll use CMPedometer data for realtime (today) steps, and HealthKit data for previous days, even if this means that there will be a slight difference in the number of steps the users sees at the end of a day and the historic record of that day, since those sources tend to report slightly different values. Is this your approach too?

Comment: You could always run a HKStatisticsQuery to get the steps accumulated so far for the current day, but your approach seems correct as well. I guess most users don't really care about the slight difference between the real time and historical data as long as they are similar and as long as the historical data is consistent, which won't be a problem with this approach. So yeah, I don't see any problems with your approach.